# glypicons not rendering on rails application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using ruby on rails with bootstrap 3.x i am using the glyphicons on the web page in rails application.I have placed the bootstrap fonts directory under
    \app\assets\fonts\

but when i add classes with `glyphicons` for html elements the glyphicons are not rendered in the web page.
for example

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
```

this renders[].
 how can i solve this and make glyphicon render on the web page?

Comment: try replacing glypicon with icon as font awesome has changed

Comment: You mentioned--"I have placed the bootstrap fonts directory under \app\assets\fonts\" Did you do the standard Bootstrap install?